# Ubuntu 14.04LTS frequent system crash!

Tags: 14.04, crash

I use a Thinkpad L440 with Ubuntu 14.04 installed. My laptop keeps freezing everynow and then.  Nothing seems to work(Mouse or keyboard). What do i do?

Comment: Check your log files for any traces of error, and narrow down the problem. It is quite dificult to investigate such a problem from remote...